Send text to Gemini API as stream
I'm building an application that is doing speech-to-text Google Cloud Speech to text and then text translation using Gemini-flash LLM.
I receive the text from the speech-to-text API as chunk, with interim text util the phrase is finish and then I receive the final transcription.
I want to send the text from the speech-to-text to the gemini API as stream, so the text is processed asap.
How can I do it ?
